# What happens to a MacBook's battery once it reaches the maximum cycle count?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power, power-management

I have a MacBook Pro and according to Apple, [its cycle count limit is 1000](https://support.apple.com/en-ph/HT201585). What happens when it surpasses 1000 cycles? Will the battery continue working or not? Will the MacBook still be able to receive power from the battery or not? Should it be replaced?

Thanks.

Comment: All I can say is that my Late 2014 MacBook Pro currently has ~1800 cycles, and, although it isn't able to hold a charge as long as before, I still get an hour of power when videoconferencing over Skype of watching a movie. Apple's 'cycle limit' is a worst-case scenario, the battery will last much longer than that.

Answer (score 5):

As it says on the page you've linked to (emphasis mine):

> Batteries have a limited amount of charge cycles before they're **considered to be consumed**. Once consumed, a **replacement battery is recommended**. You can **use your battery after it reaches its maximum cycle count**, but **you might notice a reduction in your battery life**.
>
> Knowing how many charge cycles your battery has and how many are left can help you determine when a battery replacement is required. For best performance, replace your battery when you reach its maximum cycle count.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree. You should only replace the battery once it stops holding a charge or its capacity becomes noticeably bad, unless you're under warranty and can get it for free.

Comment: I agree with you :-) Also, there is little risk of an old battery exploding or catching fire, unless the temperature sensors have died — and macOS will most certainly catch that quickly enough. If not, your Mac is already so seriously damaged that it should not be used anyway :-) So, in general, assume that you can use the battery for as long as it holds a charge, not when Apple starts "recommending" the replacement.